# How to?: Mongoid 3 and Dragonfly configuration

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid, ruby-on-rails-3.2, dragonfly-gem, mongoid3

I am trying to upgrade my app to mongoid version 3.  In my dragonfly initializer I used to have this:

```
app.configure_with(:imagemagick)
app.configure_with(:rails) do |c|
  c.datastore = Dragonfly::DataStorage::MongoDataStore.new :db => Mongoid.database
end
```

Mongoid.database no longer exists. What is the best way to configure the connection for dragonfly now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use `Mongoid.load!("config/mongoid.yml", :development)` instead of `Mongoid.database`. And it's works for me.

Comment: Awesome.  This is exactly what I was looking for.  The API changed, and I wasn't sure where to look.

Comment: A better approach is to use `Mongoid.load!('config/mongoid.yml', Rails.env)`, then you will get the current environment.